# Dependency between plugin and project inside same multi-project build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am developing a plugin for gradle for my own purposes.

I wrote a multi-project build in which I have the 2 subprojects:

- a-project
- b-plugin

This is the content of `a-project/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath project(':b-plugin')
  }
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin'
```

When the file `a-project/build.gradle` is evaluated, it doesn't find the plugin `'my-plugin'` from the project `b-plugin` because it was not built yet.

How can I fix my build files to make sure that `b-plugin` is built before `a-project/build.gradle` is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to place `b-plugin` in a folder `buildSrc/` under the root of the multi-project. This is described in the documentation of Gradle: [Build sources in the buildSrc project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec%3abuild_sources)

Then, the project `a-project` then doesn't need to specify this block anymore:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath project(':b-plugin')
  }
}
```